# <a> links not working inside <li>

Tags: html, css

I'm having a strange problem with my links inside "li" tags...

```html
  <div class="header">
    <div class="navigation">
      <ul class="nav nav-justified">
        <li><a href="index.php#sobreLnk" class="scroll">SOBRE N&Oacute;S</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.php#produtosLnk" class="scroll">PRODUTOS</a>
        </li>
        <li id="headings">
          <a href="#heading" class="scroll">
            <img src="./img/logo.png">
          </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.php#ondeLnk" class="scroll">ONDE COMPRAR</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.php#contato" class="scroll">CONTATO</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

For some reason, when I click on the links, nothing happens at all.

The links are correct, the index.php page is on the same directory, and the anchors do exist and work just fine on the index.php page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Seems to work fine in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9anmumo4/

Comment: It seems simpler now... i removed some tags that aren't really necessary for you.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the hash fragment (the part after the `#`) does not cause the page to reload, as that fragment is only available in the client. If you want the page to reload, you need to change the URL from `index.php` to something else, causing an actual request to the server.

Comment: Actually, I tried without any anchor link (simply href="index.php") and it didn't work either. So I guess the problem couldn't be related to that.

Answer (score 0):

They seem to work fine. Is this code part of index.php? The page will not scroll down if the body doesn't extend beyond the bottom of the window, so it looks like it isn't doing anything.

When I added some space, they work fine.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Just Playing</title>
        <style media="screen">
        .giveSpace{
            font-weight: bold;
            min-height: 500px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="navigation">
                    <ul class="nav nav-justified" style="margin-bottom:300px;width:100%;">
                        <li><a style="font-size:17px;font-family:Montserrat;" href="index.php#sobreLnk" class="scroll">SOBRE N&Oacute;S</a></li>
                        <li><a style="font-size:17px;font-family:Montserrat;" href="index.php#produtosLnk" class="scroll">PRODUTOS</a></li>
                        <li id="headings"><a style="color:white;font-size:17px;font-family:Montserrat;" href="#heading" class="scroll"><img src="./img/logo.png" style="width:auto;height:auto;"></a></li>
                        <li><a style="font-size:17px;font-family:Montserrat;" href="index.php#ondeLnk" class="scroll">ONDE COMPRAR</a></li>
                        <li><a style="font-size:17px;font-family:Montserrat;" href="index.php#contato" class="scroll">CONTATO</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="sobreLnk" class="giveSpace">
            sobreLnk
        </div>
        <div id="produtosLnk" class="giveSpace">
            produtosLnk
        </div>
        <div id="heading" class="giveSpace">
            heading
        </div>
        <div id="ondeLnk" class="giveSpace">
            ondeLnk
        </div>
        <div id="contato" class="giveSpace">
            contato
        </div>
    </body>
```